# Shifted heston call price

Tags: heston

If we take the heston model but change it slightly by introducing a new parameter $\alpha$ such that

[image]

is there a way to price the call option within this model as, maybe, a function of the call price within the original model? Or a function of $S_T$ as simulated from the original model?

Answer (score 2):

Let  $X_t = a S_t+(1-a)S_0$. Then
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= adS_t=a\lambda X_t \sqrt{v_t} dW^S_t,\\
X_0 &= S_0.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
\max(S_T-K, 0) &= \max\left(\frac{1}{a}X_T - \frac{1-a}{a}S_0 -K, \, 0 \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{a}\max\Big(X_T-\big(aK-aS_0+S_0\big), \, 0 \Big).
\end{align*}
You can now value the option using the previous formula or Monte Carlo approach, assuming that the underlying asset process is represented by $\{X_t, \, t \ge 0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

if we change coordinates slightly, we can regard the process as
$$
d (S+\alpha) = (S+\alpha) r dt + \lambda(S+\alpha)\sqrt{V} dW_t,
$$
so it's an option on $S+\alpha$ with $S+\alpha$ following the Heston process.
So just take the old formula and add $\alpha$ to spot and strike.